# How does Windows Integrated Authentication work with Angular?

Tags: .net, angular, iis, windows-authentication

We're looking into the possibility of using the latest version of Angular (currently v5, with v6 just around the corner) to develop some of our internal intranet web applications. So far we've exclusively used the .NET stack.

I can see a lot of articles on how to configure Windows Authentication with Angular, but none on the mechanics of it.

This is how I imagine it:

- An Angular app is hosted on an IIS server configured for NTLM integrated authentication.
- The user connects to the URL using IE and authentication negotiation is performed.
- Subsequent requests made by Angular's HTTP module now include the IIS session and authentication cookies.

Is it as simple as this? And can browsers other than IE be used in this way?